# Read Excel Dynamically in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I will have to load data from 5-6 excels (This will be depending on business)
I have to read all the sheets from an excel and each sheet names in excel should be read dynamically. And sheet names are my value/key to insert into a table. Hence I have read these into variable.

Once I read the sheet names, Each sheet has columns and their names which will vary and this has to be read again dynamically. And these will be value/key to my insert. 
I know this is complex requirement. This is something like a size upload tool where business users will give excels with data and we have to automate the same. I have come with the plan and schedule asap. Kindly help and also let me know if this is something achievable.  I don’t mind using any task or component to achieve this.

Comment: Do you know any programming languages (VB, C, C#, Java, SQL, Etc). I dont know how you can do that in SSIS. It usually wants specific, upfront, mapping.

Comment: I do know VB, C# and SQL. But this is required form ssis.

Comment: I wish you luck on this endeavour, but it is achievable if you have a full time programmer who can add code for every little anomolay that a user can add to a freeform Excel file. It is not acheivable if you want something that will work reliably. Especially when your 5-6 sheets turns into 10-15 sheets and you get users entering wierd characeter. You'd be better off developing a tool to enter this directly into a database (even if this tool just accepts copy/paste from Excel).